# GET not returning sent message. Only inbox items

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

When a user sends a message, it generates a messageTrackingId. Right now it $unwinds the creatorName as a unique returned value in inbox. I want only one user entry. No duplicates of the same user. Currently though they can send multiple messages if the other user hasn't responded generating new messageTrackingIds as a result. How can I make the initial sent message appear in the inbox as well so that I can use that messageTrackingId instead of generating new ones? I've been stuck on this for awhile so I appreciate any help.

app.get

```
app.get('/api/messages', (req, res, next) => {
  query = {};
  inbox = false;
  messageId = false;
  if (req.query.recipientId) {
    query = { recipientId: req.query.recipientId }
    inbox = true;

    Messages.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
            $or: [ { recipientId: req.query.recipientId  }, { creator: req.query.recipientId  } ]
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            conversant: {
                $cond: [ { $ne: [ "$recipientId", req.query.recipientId  ] }, "$recipientId", "$creator" ]
            }
        }
    },
      {
          $sort: { creationDate: 1 }
      },
      {
          $group: {
              _id: "$conversant",
              message: { $first: "$message" },
              recipientId: { $first: "$recipientId" },
              creator: { $first: "$creator" },
              messageTrackingId: { $first: "$messageTrackingId" },
              creationDate: { $first: "$creationDate" }
          }
      },
       {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "creator",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "creatorName",
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                _id: 1,
                message: { $arrayElemAt: ["$message", 0] },
                recipientId: { $arrayElemAt: ["$recipientId", 0] },
                creator: { $arrayElemAt: ["$creator", 0] },
                messageTrackingId: { $arrayElemAt: ["$messageTrackingId", 0] },
                creatorName: { $arrayElemAt: ["$creatorName", 0] },

              }
            }
          ],
          as: 'messageTest'
        },
      }
  ])



      //.populate('creator', 'username')

      .then(documents => {
        if (res.subject === "Test") {
        }
        if (inbox === false && messageId === false) {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "User's Sent Messages Retrieved!",
            posts: documents
          });
        }
        if (inbox === true) {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "User's Inbox Retrieved!",
            posts: documents
          });
        }
        if (messageId === true) {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "Message Chain Retrieved!",
            posts: documents
          });
        }
      });
  } else if (req.query.creator) {
    query = { creator: req.query.creator };
    inbox = false;
    Messages.find(query)
      .populate("creator", "username")
      .then(documents => {
        if (inbox === false && messageId === false) {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "User's Sent Messages Retrieved!",
            posts: documents
          });
        }
        if (inbox === true) {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "User's Inbox Retrieved!",
            posts: documents
          });
        }
        if (messageId === true) {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "Message Chain Retrieved!",
            posts: documents
          });
        }
      });
  } else if (req.query.messageId) {
    query = { messageTrackingId: req.query.messageId };
    messageId = true;
    Messages.find(query)
      .populate("creator", "instagramName")
      .then(documents => {
        if (inbox === false && messageId === false) {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "User's Sent Messages Retrieved!",
            posts: documents
          });
        }
        if (inbox === true) {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "User's Inbox Retrieved!",
            posts: documents
          });
        }
        if (messageId === true) {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "Message Chain Retrieved!",
            posts: documents
          });
        }
      });
  }
});
```

app.post

```
app.post("/api/messages", checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Made It")
  messagingTrackingIDValue = "";

  const messaging = new Messages({
    creator: req.userData.userId,
    recipient: req.body.recipient,
    recipientId: req.body.recipientId,
    message: req.body.message,
    //message: req.body.message,
    messageTrackingId: req.body.messageTrackingId,
    creatorName: req.userData.username,
    creationDate: req.body.creationDate
  });

  //saves to database with mongoose
  messaging.save().then(result => {
    if (result.creator !== messaging.creator) {
    } else if (result.creator === req.userData.userId) {
    }
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "Message Sent Successfully!",
      postId: result._id
    });
  });
});
```

angular service

```
  sendMessage(
    recipient: string,
    message: string,
    creationDate: Date,
    recipientId: string,
    creatorName: string,
    messageTrackingId: string
  ) {
    const messaging: Messages = {
      id: null,
      recipient: recipient,
      message: message,
      creationDate: creationDate,
      creator: null,
      recipientId: recipientId,
      creatorName: creatorName,
      messageTrackingId: messageTrackingId
    };

    this.http
      .post<{ message: string; messagingId: string; creator: string }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/messages",
        messaging
      )
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        console.log(responseData);
        const id = responseData.messagingId;
        messaging.id = id;

        console.log("Message sent successfully!");

        //   window.location.reload();
        //  this.posts.push();
        //  this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
      });
  }




  replyToMessage(
    recipient: string,
    message: string,
    creationDate: Date,
    recipientId: string,
    creatorName: string,
    messageTrackingId: string
  ) {
    const messaging: Messages = {
      id: null,
      recipient: recipient,
      message: message,
      creationDate: creationDate,
      creator: null,
      recipientId: recipientId,
      creatorName: creatorName,
      messageTrackingId: messageTrackingId
    };

    this.http
      .post<{ message: string; messagingId: string; creator: string }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/messages",
        messaging
      )
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        console.log(responseData);
        const id = responseData.messagingId;
        messaging.id = id;

        console.log("Message sent successfully!");
      });
  }







  getMessages(recipientId: string) {
    return this.http
      .get<{
        message: string;
        posts: any;
        maxPosts: number;
        messageList: string;
      }>("http://localhost:3000/api/messages?recipientId=" + recipientId)
      .pipe(
        map(retrievedData => {
          return {
            posts: retrievedData.posts.map(post => {
              return {
                creator: post.creator,
                recipientId: post.recipientId,
                creationDate: post.creationDate,
                messageTrackingId: post.messageTrackingId,
                creatorName: post.creatorName,
                id: post._id
              };
            }),
            maxPosts: retrievedData.maxPosts
          };
        })
      );
  }
```

Here's an example of the recipient replying to message so sender gets messageTrackingId to use

First message and then reply message. Since the recipient replied, the sender has the messageTrackingId to use for next message to same user.

```
Made It
{ _id: 5e0674ddd55aae5294370870,
  creator: 5df0014e25ee451beccf588a,
  recipient: 'joe',
  recipientId: '5df00d08c713f722909c99c1',
  message: 'This is the initial message',
  messageTrackingId: '3cb3f5bb-5e17-49a7-8aca-4a61ddd1d847',
  creatorName: 'andy',
  creationDate: 2019-12-27T21:17:17.155Z,
  __v: 0 }
Made It
{ _id: 5e067529d55aae5294370872,
  creator: 5df00d08c713f722909c99c1,
  recipient: 'andy',
  recipientId: '5df0014e25ee451beccf588a',
  message: 'This is the reply message',
  messageTrackingId: '3cb3f5bb-5e17-49a7-8aca-4a61ddd1d847',
  creatorName: 'joe',
  creationDate: 2019-12-27T21:18:33.947Z,
  __v: 0 }
```

If recipient never replies and sender sends another message this happens:

```
Made It
{ _id: 5e06756bd55aae5294370873,
  creator: 5df00d08c713f722909c99c1,
  recipient: 'andy',
  recipientId: '5df0014e25ee451beccf588a',
  message: 'This is the first message',
  messageTrackingId: '2077a8e6-844c-4639-a4fa-7aee0b8beaf4',
  creatorName: 'joe',
  creationDate: 2019-12-27T21:19:39.217Z,
  __v: 0 }
Made It
{ _id: 5e06757cd55aae5294370874,
  creator: 5df00d08c713f722909c99c1,
  recipient: 'andy',
  recipientId: '5df0014e25ee451beccf588a',
  message: 'This is another message to same user.',
  messageTrackingId: 'feeb0e20-432e-4c9a-9f59-45913c194edc',
  creatorName: 'joe',
  creationDate: 2019-12-27T21:19:56.257Z,
  __v: 0 }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add sample documents and say what is the expected output?

Comment: I added some scenario documents above.

Comment: You had better to add documents as text so that we can copy paste and try.

Comment: I added console.log(result) and outputted results above

Comment: @user6680 could you explain what is the expected aggregation output for given data and why ?

Comment: The expected aggregation output would look basically like an SMS app. It lists all the people you've had conversations with and when you click one, it does a GET with all the messages in a message chain on the next page. The aggregation is the first part that grabs messages by recipientID with unique messageTrackingIDs so if a user sends another message without receiving a reply, then the recipient gets 2 entries from the other user instead of being consolidated since it generates a new messageTrackingId

Comment: @user6680 thank you ! Does `req.query.recipientId` represent a person you want to display a list of messages for ?

Comment: Yes. recipientId is the id of the logged in user from mongodb User table. So they would be checking their messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below aggregation to make sure that there will be only one document returned for every (`recipient`, `sender`) pair:

```
db.Messages.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: { conversants: [ "$recipientId", "$creator" ] }
    },
    {
        $match: { conversants: req.query.recipientId }
    },
    {
        $addFields: { conversant: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$conversants", cond: { $ne: [ "$$this", "5df0014e25ee451beccf588a" ] } }  } , 0 ] } }
    },
    {
        $sort: { creationDate: 1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$conversant",
            message: { $first: "$message" },
            recipientId: { $first: "$recipientId" },
            creator: { $first: "$creator" },
            messageTrackingId: { $first: "$messageTrackingId" },
            creationDate: { $first: "$creationDate" }
        }
    },        
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            let: { creator: "$creator" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$creator" ] } } },
                { $project: { creatorName: 1 } }
            ],
            as: "creatorName"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: { creatorName: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$creatorName", 0 ] } }
    }
])
```

The idea here is that you create additional field which represents two ids: `creator` and `recipient`. This will allow you to do two things: filter using `recipientId` (who may also be the sender) - step two, and select `conversant` value which is always the second person - no matter if a person specified in your request sent or received a message in that conversation. Then you can `$group` on that field to make sure that you'll get only single message in every "conversation". Instead of using `$addToSet` with `$arrayElemAt` you can just run `$first`. Relatively heavy `$lookup` can also be run as a last step since you need to get that data once per "conversant".

EDIT: first three stages can be replaced with below stages - that should significantly improve performance since the filtering will be applied as soon as possible:

```
{
    $match: {
        $or: [ { recipientId: req.query.recipientId  }, { creator: req.query.recipientId  } ]
    }
},
{
    $addFields: { 
        conversant: { 
            $cond: [ { $ne: [ "$recipientId", req.query.recipientId  ] }, "$recipientId", "$creator" ] 
        } 
    }
},
```

Comment: I updated my code above to reflect your answer. I also added a couple screenshots of both user inboxes. When I send the message, the sender never gets anything in their inbox and the recipient gets [Object object]

Comment: I would recommend testing the query directly on your database. Here's how I did that: I've entered single document (`5e0674ddd55aae5294370870`) into a new collection and tried to run this query from Mongo shell to see if it works for `creator` (`5df0014e25ee451beccf588a`) and `recipient` (`5df00d08c713f722909c99c1`). Then you can start adding more documents to test the edge case you're encountering. The way it gets displayed should be easiest to fix.

Comment: Could my issue be related to the fact that the creator is an ObjectId? see new pic above for reference

Comment: I think it has something to do with the ObjectId of creator because I manually created a document like you suggested and the second document in that pic GET into app fine, but the first one won't. See new image above.

Comment: I got it figured out by changing the match to this  $match: {
          $or: [
            { recipientId: req.query.recipientId },
            { creator: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.recipientId) }
          ]
        }
I just need to figure out the Object object issue on the front end now. The response from the server doesn't return username the same as before causing the issue in angular mat-table, but I'll try to figure that out. Thanks!

Comment: @user6680 that would be my next suggestion, I'm glad you've figured that out on your own :)

Comment: One other thing I noticed is that your solution returns too much information under creatorName. It was only supposed to return the name. Things like password are coming back in GET. See pic above for reference

Comment: @user6680 you can apply `$project` after `$lookup` to select only the fields you need

Comment: I think I'm close, but it's saying MongoError: $arrayElemAt's first argument must be an array, but is string with the $project.  Do you know why? I added additional code above

Comment: @user6680 you can run `$arrayElemAt` and then `$project` as a next step or try to run `$project` inside of `$lookup` like here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries

Comment: It keeps saying Error: $lookup with 'pipeline' may not specify 'localField' or 'foreignField'  I added the pipeline per the documentation, but can't get past this error. I updated code above

Comment: @user6680 modified my answer - you've mixed two `$lookup` syntaxes - that's why you're seeing this error. You can add more fields in `$project` if you need

Comment: I got it sorted out and working now. Thanks for all your help!